# How do I list all data in react native firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to see the posts made by all users. so i want to get all data regardless of user id

```
 function storePostData(){
    
    firebase.firestore().collection('Post')
    .doc(userId)
    .collection('userPost').get()
    .then((querySnapshot)=>{
      querySnapshot.forEach(snapshot=>{
        let data = snapshot.data();
      })
    })
  }
```

[image]

This data structure

---Post
-----userId
-----userPost
-------randomName(Post data)

Comment: If you `console.log(user)` right before the query, what does it output? Please edit your question to show both the updated code and its output.

Comment: I would suggest not using an array at all. Array's are a bit challenging in NoSQL databases - there are lots of posts about that here on SO. A good option is to generate a document for each post and store those documents within the posts collection.